# How to setup Skia and Angle with a DirectX12 device

Tags: directx, hook, angle, skia, directx-12

today I may have a more difficult question.

I am hooking a program with DirectX12. The hook gives me the IDXGISwapChain3 on Present, so I can draw over it every frame. I already did some DirectX11 and 12 hooks before, but I am asking how would I setup Skia / Angle from a ID3D11Device.

Before you now answer, I know that I don't have to use that, but I want to, otherwise I would not ask.

So I was looking around in the internet, but I didn't any good documentations on how to do that correctly, but I am pretty sure that it is possible.

So this is what I expect to see:

1. Initializing EGL with the already existing DirectX11 Device
2. Initializing Skia with EGL (not sure?)

If you have worked with EGL or Skia before, please answer. This would help me so much.
:D

**Edit**:

My goal is to be able to draw on SkCanvas every single frame over the hooked program (which uses DirectX12).

**Edit2:**

After trial and error I discovered that I can make a GrContext with a DirectX12 device:

```cpp
GrD3DBackendContext c;
c.fAdapter = ...;
c.fDevice = device...;
...
auto cx = GrContext::MakeDirect3D(c);
```

How then would I make my surface with it?

```cpp
SkSurface surface = SkSurface::Make...
```